# flycheck wrapper function for bundler

Tags: flycheck

I would like to make flycheck work with checkers installed via Bundler, and I've read that in order to do that, I have to implement the [`flycheck-command-wrapper-function`](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/blob/master/flycheck.el#L426).

What it should do is prepend `command` with `bundle exec`.

[This](https://github.com/travisbhartwell/nix-emacs/blob/master/README.org#flycheck) is an implementation of such a wrapper for Haskell.

I'm a total newbie when it comes to Lisp, so I could only come up with

```
(setq flycheck-command-wrapper-function
      (lambda (command) (funcall "bundle exec " command))
)
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it'd be:

```
(setq flycheck-command-wrapper-function
      (lambda (command)
        (append '("bundle" "exec") command)))
```

I think that there's a misunderstanding here, and I see that `command` is quite a confusing name here.

You can't use `funcall` here because `command` is not an Emacs Lisp interactive command—i.e. what you'd execute with `M-x`—in this case.  It's a list of strings that constitute an executable command for the operating system.  Essentially it's what you'd type into your shell to run a syntax checker, although Flycheck does not use the shell to run its commands for safety and efficiency reasons.

Right before it's about to execute such a command for a syntax checker Flycheck gives to whole command as argument to `flycheck-command-wrapper-function`.  The function must then return another, potentially entirely different, list which is the command that Flycheck will subsequently execute without any further checks.

To run a syntax checker through bundle we just need to return the command with `bundle exec` prepended.  Mind you, Flycheck doesn't use the shell so you need to pass `bundle exec` as *two* separate list items.

I hope that this clears up things a little bit.