# How to make flycheck checker 'ruby-rubocop' use 'bundle exec rubocop' as executable?

Tags: flycheck, ruby

I want `ruby-rubocop` Flycheck syntax checker to execute `bundle exec rubocop` instead of just `rubocop`.

What I've tried:

1. `(setq flycheck-ruby-rubocop-executable "bundle exec rubocop")`

   Results in following error:

   ```
   Error while checking syntax automatically: (error "Output file descriptor of flycheck-ruby-rubocop is closed")
   ```
2. `(flycheck-set-checker-executable 'ruby-rubocop "bundle exec rubocop")`

   I get error:

   ```
   user-error: bundle exec rubocop is no executable
   ```
3. [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21958/13425):

   ```
   (setq flycheck-command-wrapper-function
     (lambda (command)
       (append '("bundle" "exec") command)))
   ```

   It broke all checkers, because now it appends "bundle exec" to all checkers, not only ruby-rubocop, and it didn't work in ruby buffer (it still used `rubocop` without `bundle exec`). I don't know how to make this variable buffer-local.

Answer (score 4):

Use `setq-local` to make a variable buffer-local. It works well in a hook like this:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq-local flycheck-command-wrapper-function
                (lambda (command) (append '("bundle" "exec") command)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll let someone else clear that issue up for Flycheck.

But for completeness' sake: if you install Emacs 27 (or newer) and enable `flymake-mode` in Ruby buffers, Rubocop integration is there, and it appends `"bundle exec"` when appropriate.